# At what point does the Newton Raphson method fail to converge?

Tags: numerical-methods

An equation f(x)=0 has 2 roots in the interval between 0 and 8. What is the value or a description for which the Newton Raphson method will fail to converge?

Comment: You haven't given enough information for there to be anything more than a tautological answer to your question.  Do you know anything about $f$, other than it having 2 roots? If not, there's not much to say.

Comment: This depends largely on the shape of the graph, and on the choice of starting point, $x_0$.  In particular if their are horizontal tangents or vertical asymptotes in the interval [0,8], Newton's method may fail.

Comment: In general, this is a very difficult question. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal for instance.

Answer (score 2):

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton-Raphson#2._Failure_of_the_method_to_converge_to_the_root%3a). Since you're asking about a function with a multiple root, you probably want the answer in section 3.